# Bash script run order, why does it queue the read command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm very confused at the moment.

What I want to do is create a listener function, that wait for two commands - and the thing is it should only listen every two hundred milliseconds and ignore the other input from the user.

```
function foo() {

    read -sN1 _input

    case "${_input}" in

        A) echo 'Option A';;
        B) echo 'Option B';;
    esac
}

while true; do
    sleep 0.2
    foo
done
```

If I "hammer" the A-key (or UP-key) ten times, it writes "Option A" ten times (although, slowly) - when it should only had time to write it at most three times. Why is that - and how do I fix it?

Comment: You'll need a timeout on your `read` as well, or your program will wait indefinitely for input after the initial 200-ms sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with that worked. It isn't *very* nice, but it works.

```
function inputCommand() {

    _now=`date +%s%N | cut -b1-13`
    _time=$(($_now-$_timeout))

    if [ $_time -gt 500 ]; then
            $1
            _timeout=`date +%s%N | cut -b1-13`
    fi
}

function keyPressUp() {

    echo "Key Press Up"
}

function waitForInput() {

    unset _input
    read -sN1 _input

    case "${_input}" in

            A) inputCommand "keyPressUp";;
    esac
}

while true; do

        waitForInput
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Your terminal buffers the input to your program. In order to make your program ignore the input it received while it sleeps, you should clear the input buffer before calling `read`. To my knowledge there is not way to do this in bash.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your sleep function within a block where stdin is closed:

```
  {
    sleep 0.2
  } <&-
```

Alternatively, you can clear (read and discard) the stdin buffer right after the sleep:

```
sleep 0.2
read -t 1 -n 10000 discard
```

Comment: this sounds like a good idea, never got it to work though. It somehow messes with the second read command and nothing gets read. However, I came up with a different solution - see below.